# How do you feel about someone using one of your pictures from the internet?

Tags: internet, privacy

How do you feel if someone used one of your pictures that you posted on the internet? As I novice photographer I feel good that my picture is good enough but is that right? I do not like making my pictures ugly by pasting a huge watermark across the image.

Comment: Hi @Vaishak, this is really too much of a poll for our site here.  Take a look at the [FAQ](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) for what kinds of questions are more appropriate here.  If you've got some more questions that would benefit the site structure, we'd love to have them.

Answer (score 5):

How you *feel* about things is an utterly subjective thing, depending on (among other things) what was your intent when taking/publishing the photo and the context where the image is used. For example, you might feel robbed when you worked hard hoping to earn money for a photo and then discover it somewhere used or even shared without your consent. Or you might feel delighted finding out that local newspaper has printed a big copy of the image you took to share the beauty of your back garden with your friends. And you might feel furious seconds after, when you discover the photo is illustrating an article on zealous use of pesticides.

Nobody can tell you how to feel about things. A feeling cannot be wrong or right, it's an emotional thing.